# PowerShell. Удалённая установка приложения с параметрами

Tags: powershell, windowsinstaller

Требуется написать PowerShell-скрипт, который бы выполнял тихую установку приложения на сервере.
Локальная установка выполняется успешно такой командой (в командной строке):

```
msiexec /i "\\srv\distr\MQServer\MSI\IBM WebSphere MQ.msi" /l*v "%temp%\MQ.log" /q TRANSFORMS="1033.mst" USEINI="\\srv\distr\MQServer\Response.ini"
```

Пробую запустить скрипт PowerShell локально - не получается. Скрипт такой:

```
$arg = "'/i "'c:\distr\MQServer\MSI\IBM WebSphere MQ.msi'" /l*v "%temp%\MQ.log" /q TRANSFORMS = "1033.mst" USEINI = "c:\distr\MQServer\Response.ini"'"
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $arg -wait -passthru
```

Ошибка:

```
Неожиданный токен "c:\distr\MQServer\MSI\IBM WebSphere MQ.msi" в выражении или инструкции.
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\install_MQ_local.ps1:1 знак:58
+ $arg = "/i "'c:\distr\MQServer\MSI\IBM WebSphere MQ.msi' <<<< " /l*v "%temp%\MQ.log" /q TRANSFORMS = "1033.mst" USEINI = "c:\distr\MQServer\Response.ini""
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (c:\distr\MQServ...ebSphere MQ.msi:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Пробовал по разному - заключал путь и весь аргумент в одинарные, двойные кавычки, фигурные скобки. Пробовал писать не в переменную, а в ArgumentList - не получается, появляются разные ошибки.
Если локально скрипт будет работать, нужно его запустить на уделённом компьютере, например следующая команда сработает или посоветуете другой способ?

```
$script = Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $arg -wait -passthru    
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server2 -ScriptBlock $script
```

Скрипт должен запускаться на Windows 7 и Windows Server 2008 R2, соответственно PowerShell версии 2.

Comment: А Что вам мешает написать `msiexec /i ...`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в таком случае появляется окно со справкой, как будто я просто запустил msiexec.exe. Похоже слеш PowerShell не воспринимает.
Также пробовал msiexec --% /i ..., но видимо во второй версии PowerShell --% не работает :(

Comment: а если в кавычки заключить?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, нет, тоже самое

Comment: @Dimabmrec `'/i "c:\distr\MQServer\MSI\IBM WebSphere MQ.msi"'` в этой конструкции ошибка была

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, а где? Если в кавычках, то я по разному пробовал.

Comment: @Dimabmrec вот так пробуйте `'/i "c:\distr\MQServer\MSI\IBM WebSphere MQ.msi"'`

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, не, я так пробовал - не получается.

Answer (score -1):

Решил обходным путём с помощью psexec.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    $computer,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    $adminusername,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    $adminpassword
    )  
C:\distr\PSTools\PsExec64.exe \\$computer -s -u $adminusername -p $adminpassword -accepteula -nobanner msiexec /i "\\srv\distr\MQServer\MSI\IBM WebSphere MQ.msi" /l*v "C:\MQ.log" /q TRANSFORMS="1033.mst" USEINI="\\srv\distr\MQServer\Response.ini"
```